# Is there not a more simple way to select all classes in an array without a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there not a simple way to grab all of the elements with a class, instead of doing a for loop?

So instead of doing:

```
box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
    box[i]style.display = "none";
}
```

We can do:

```
/* Imagine a symbol for all is ¬ for example */

box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
box[¬]style.display = "none";
```

Maybe there is a more simple way to do this already that I do not know about?

Edit: Sorry just to mention, the display: none is more so just an example

Comment: Fundamentally no. If you use libraries like jQuery, they allow you to write something more like code #2, but internally they still need to loop…

Comment: Setting inline styles should be avoided whenever possible. If you just want to show/hide _all_ boxes together - then do it via a rule in your stylesheet. `.hideAllBoxes .box { display: none; }` - now you just have to add the class `hideAllBoxes` on a common ancestor element, and all boxes will hide.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(box => box.style.display = 'none')` is maybe simpler, though still looping. You can of course set the class in the function as well.

Answer (score 1):

when you use document.querySelectorAll it returns nodelist so there is only one way of array to apply your changes for each element.